# Serious lag issues with Deus Ex: Human Revolution

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Just had a new custom rig built. It has dual Radeon 6970 2GB running in crossfire and AMD's FX-8150 CPU 8 core processer. I've got 8G of ram.

This game is running horribly with this set up. I don't know what's wrong but unless I'm missing something I should be able to run this game maxed out with no issues.

However, when I click off all the bells and wistles (v-sync, triple buffering, etc) and turn the resolution down to minimal, it is still the laggiest thing I've ever witnessed.

Even the OPTION MENUS LAG.

So bottom line, no part of this game runs as it was meant to and I have no clue why. If anyone on here can offer an explanation it would be much appreciated. I loved Deus Ex and was a fan of invisible war as well and was really looking forward to playing this. It's one of the reasons I threw up the money to buy the rig I described. Annnnd now it looks like I might as well have bought an E-machine...

Comment: sigh @ AMD.  Anyway, does any other games lag or just DEHR?

Comment: Have you tried spending a Praxis point in Lag Resistance? ;)

Comment: The only other game I've installed thus far is Oblivion. It runs good on high settings, though not ultra which surprised me. But just being able to run it on high without lag is definitely good enough for me

Comment: @agent86 har har

Comment: with that setup, there should be absolutely no way you shouldn't be able to run oblivion smoothly on ultra.  I suspect you got a custom built machine?  Try putting it through some benchmarks and make sure all your bios/drivers are up to date.  There might be a weird bottlneck somewhere in your system.

Comment: Are all the drivers up to date (Including the BIOS)? Had the same issue a while back, which was caused by the BIOS version not being up to date, and not recognizing my CPU properly, so it didn't set the CPU frequency correctly.

Comment: Checked the video cards drivers through the control center they came with and they were good to go. I'm staring at instructions for updating BIOS as we speak. 

@yx. do you have a recommendation for what benchmarks I should try

Comment: @mordi2k so there is a newer version of my BIOS but when I downloaded it, it claims that it doesn't support the 64 bit version of windows 7 that I'm running. 

How could that be when the previous version of the BIOS that I'm running obviously did

Comment: Might be that it requires some other form of installation, [try reading this](http://www.wikihow.com/Update-Your-Computer%27s-BIOS) as it explains it pretty well.

Comment: @Entreri 3dmark and pcmark are typically the standard ones, putting it through the pacing of some modern games works well too (Not sure which ones you have access to). But your rig should max out everything with no problems unless something is wrong.

Comment: Is your copy of Deus Ex an original copy? Some bootlegged ones may cause unecessary lag because of bad code.

Comment: Oblivion is pretty badly optimized. Google 'Pyffi Oblivion meshes' for some insight.

Answer (score 2):

First - update your video card drivers. And Direct X. This can help. Also, upgrade all the drivers on critical systems. Then, if this doesn't help, lower all the settings - and try to raise them one by one; maybe you'll find something that makes your PC lag.

You could try to Ctrl+Alt+Del after launching the game and monitor how much CPU and RAM the dehr.exe process "eats". Maybe it's not game's problem, maybe you just got something running in the background and hanging your system, or possibly some kind of virus.

Answer (score 0):

Bad lag on the Missing Link DLC or the Director's Cut edition may be due to a configuration issue, especially if you use an nVidia graphics card, and double-especially if you have a laptop with switchable graphics. See [Why is Deus Ex:HR very slow and laggy when I play the Missing Link DLC or the new Director's Cut?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137818/why-is-deus-exhr-very-slow-and-laggy-when-i-play-the-missing-link-dlc-or-the-ne) .

---

In your specific circumstance, it may be an issue with your graphics driver configuration, specifically something called an "SLI profile".

[This link](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/deus-ex-human-revolution-director-s-cut-617822/fix-for-the-bad-pc-performance-nvidia-and-sli-user-1457096/) talks about a similar issue with nVidia SLI rigs, and gives a fix. Admittedly, you have a ATI/AMD Radeon SLI setup, but the link may offer some insight regardless.

I don't own an SLI rig so I can't comment too much further.