# Why is Deus Ex:HR very slow and laggy when I play the Missing Link DLC or the new Director's Cut?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Why do I have such terrible graphics performance when I play the *Missing Link DLC* or *Director's Cut* editions of Deus Ex : Human Revolution?

When I play the original DX:HR, I can play full screen at 1920×1200 resolution with high graphics settings.

When playing either The Missing Link or the new Director's Cut, the game is unplayably slow.  Setting a lower screen resolution and turning down the graphics settings helps, but the game looks very bad.

How can I improve performance of DX:HR; The Missing Link, and DX:HR; Director's Cut?

I am playing on a Dell XPS 17 laptop (L702x) with nVidia/Intel switchable graphics, i.e. nVidia Optimus which switches between integrated and discrete graphics cards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These problems with DX:HR are due to:

1. a [bug in DX:HR](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/deus-ex-human-revolution-director-s-cut-617822/fix-for-the-bad-pc-performance-nvidia-and-sli-user-1457096/), which is easy to correct via registry settings.
2. an nVidia driver issue when using switchable graphics, which is easily corrected in the nVidia driver settings.

## 1. Registry Settings

[Two registry fixes are required.](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/deus-ex-human-revolution-director-s-cut-617822/fix-for-the-bad-pc-performance-nvidia-and-sli-user-1457096/)

1. Set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC\AllowJobStealing` to `0`.
2. for NVIDIA owners - set registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Eidos\Deus Ex: HRDC\Graphics\AtiForceFetch4` to `0`.

## 2. nVidia driver settings

If you are playing on a laptop with nVidia switchable graphics, i.e. switchable Intel integrated/nVidia discrete graphics cards, you will need to apply this fix.

The issue is that the nVidia driver determines when to switch to the high-performance nVidia graphics card based on the *name of the program executable being run*. `DXHR.exe` is on the list of "programs requiring high-performance graphics", but `DXHRML.exe` (the Missing Link) and `DXHRDC.exe` (Director's Cut) are not on this list.

The solution is to manually tell the nVidia driver that you would like `DXHRDC.exe` to be run using the high-performance graphics card.

1. Open the nVidia Control Panel.

   [image]
2. Under `Select a Task`, open the `3D Settings` > `Manage 3D Settings` pane.

   [image]
3. Click the `Add` button to add a new program. Find your DXHR executable - mine is located at `D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Deus Ex Human Revolution Director's Cut\DXHRDC.exe`.

   [image]
4. Tell the nVidia driver that you always want to run `DXHRDC.exe` using the `High-performance nVidia processor`.

   [image]

---

After applying these fixes, I am able to play the Director's Cut at the same graphics settings as the original Deus Ex: HR - that is, full-screen 1920×1200 at high graphics settings.

Comment: If you're going to look for answers yourself for these kind of questions in the future, please refrain yourself from asking the questions here. Unless you're absolutely clueless.

Comment: @VascovdEng: [It is officially encouraged to ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) if you have a high quality question and a high quality answer. It adds to the body of knowledge and means there's a comprehensive answer which otherwise wouldn't exist.

Comment: My bad, carry on then.

Comment: @VascovdEng: [See also](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).